# A number that shows trend, especially regression

Tags: regression, trend

I apologize for the vague title, I am not quite able to form my question except by giving an example.

I am trying to quantify the regression in some aspects of software development process.

Take for example code coverage. Our software consists of a large number of `units` of different sizes, and the build process includes `tests` which also measure code coverage.

Now consider that we want to monitor the change in code coverage from week to week, and quickly identify units that are whose coverage is dropping, with additional weight to larger units.

So suppose the following data is available:

```
Unit   Loc   Curr -1  -2  -3  -4  Notes
unit1  1200   90  88  86  88  85  improving, good
unit2  1500   85  82  80  75  95  improving but far below best, needs attention
unit3  8000   80  82  83  83  84  slowly regressing, needs attention
unit4  5000   85  88  85  88  84  goes up and down, its ok
```

So instead of these hand-written notes I am looking for a number that can be calculated which can give similar information.

Comment: Your notes seem to describe characteristics along disparate dimensions: they point out not only trends, but all compare recent data to maxima and identify oscillation (or variability). To do so with a single number is impossible *unless you specify how each dimension is to be equated with the others.*

Comment: @whuber can you please explain how the dimensions have to be equated, maybe with an example? I do not understand the terms but "comparing to maxima" seems to be what I explains as "far below best". What is oscillation/variability? Does it refer to the "goes up and down"? How to I track slow regression in unit3?

Comment: The three attributes mentioned in the example--trend, comparison to maximum, and oscillation ("goes up and down")--function in the same way you might evaluate a fruit for, say, size, color, and taste.  Given a numeric rating in each of these three dimensions, you still have to decide how to combine the size, color, and taste numbers into a *single* number that reflects your overall opinion of the fruit.  It's the same here: nobody can tell you what your overall opinion of the SW development process should be; it's up to you to decide how to combine its attributes into a single number.